# Detect when at last character when character is multibyte

Tags: unicode

I have the following command for `\` that jumps to the last character unless the cursor is under the last character, in which case it jumps to the start of the line.

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> \ ((col(".") >= col("$")-1) ? "^" : "$")
```

It works great most of the time unless the final character is a multibyte char, e.g. the 1-line file `multibyte.txt` (given below)

```
aaaaaaaaaa的的的的的的的
```

`\` moves to the end of the line, but repeatedly pressing it keeps it there.

Is it possible to detect whether the cursor is at the last byte in a line, regardless of the number of bytes that make up the character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `col()` returns the byte offset of the cursor in the current line. The returned value is the offset of the first byte of a multi-byte character.

You could use `virtcol()` instead. It returns the screen column of the character.

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> \ ((virtcol(".") >= virtcol("$")-1) ? "^" : "$")
```

In a short test it also works, when the last char is double-width.